# Org mode: how to define a path variable to my org file directory?

Tags: org-mode

I have code for defining org capture like:

```
(setq org-capture-templates '(((
         "t"               ; key
         "Todo"            ; description
         entry             ; type
         (file+headline "C:/Users/myname/Dropbox/Privat/org/abc.org" "todo"); target
         "* TODO [#B] %^{Todo} \n From: %a\n\n%?"  ; template
         :prepend t        ; properties
     )))
```

This code sends the generated TODO item into the org file `abc.org`, located at `C:/Users/myname/Dropbox/Privat/org/`, the target. If I want to change the location of the target to e.g. `C:/Users/myname/org/`, I could either do this by changing the path description inside the capture code, or better, define a path variable outside capture, telling where org file is located, and using this inside the target description like:

`(file+headline "myPathVariable/abc.org" "todo"); target`

where `myPathVariable = "C:/Users/myname/org"`.

How do I define such a path variable?

Thanks for all help : )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3730784 has some useful pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you already familar with the built-in `org-directory` variable?
This is the default directory for org files, and will be used as the
base directory for capture templates that specify a relative path.

You could just use `(file+headline "abc.org" "todo")` and set
`org-directory` as appropriate.